# JRadio Buttons and images

Tags: java

I am currently teaching myself the java language and I now learing about GUI's by using eclpise, JFrame, and window builder.  I have created a GUI with two radiobutton and above them I have two labels each with a picture on them.  When I click on the radiobutton on the left I want the left label to display the image and the right label to display nothing.  And then when I click on the right radio button I want the label on the right to display the image.  I am stuck and i've tried a few different things and was hoping for some guidance. Here is some of the code so far

```
JLabel lblLeft = new JLabel("");
//This is to retrieve your image and put it in the GUI
Image imgL = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource    ("schlange.gif")).getImage();  
    lblLeft.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgL));
    lblLeft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(290, 26));
    lblLeft.setOpaque(true);
    lblLeft.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    contentPane.add(lblLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JLabel lblRight = new JLabel("");
    //This is to retrieve your image and put it in the GUI 
    Image imgR = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("schlange.gif")).getImage();  
    lblRight.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgR));
    lblRight.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(290, 26));
    lblRight.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    lblRight.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.add(lblRight, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //To get this code to come up you click on your radio button then right click on it go down to add event
    //then go to item and itemStateChanged 
    JRadioButton rdbtnLeft = new JRadioButton("Left");
    rdbtnLeft.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) 
        {
            lblLeft.setIcon((Icon) imgL);
        }
    });


    buttonGroupLeftRight.add(rdbtnLeft);
    rdbtnLeft.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    panel.add(rdbtnLeft);

    JRadioButton rdbtnRight = new JRadioButton("Right");
    buttonGroupLeftRight.add(rdbtnRight);
    rdbtnRight.setToolTipText("                                ");
    rdbtnRight.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    panel.add(rdbtnRight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each image in its own JPanel (leftImagePanel and rightImagePanel).

Then you can use:

```
leftImagePanel.setVisible(true);
rightImagePanel.setVisible(false);
```

or

```
leftImagePanel.setVisible(false);
rightImagePanel.setVisible(true);
```

Wherever you need.